# ContentValues update failed in Android Q if music is locates in external SD card

Tags: android, external, sd-card

I use below code to change music type to ringtone. It works if Android version below Q, but got crash in Android Q. The problem is musicFile.getAbsolutePath() return path of external SD card. There is no problem if music is locate in internal storage.
How could I update contentvalue if music in external SD card?

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put("_data", musicFile.getAbsolutePath());
contentValues.put("title", title);
contentValues.put("mime_type", "audio/*");
contentValues.put("is_ringtone", true);
```

Comment: "There is no problem if music is locate in internal storage" -- there should be, as `_data` is deprecated. "How could I update contentvalue if music in external SD card?" -- use the ID, not the `_data`. Get the ID of the song, assemble a `Uri` for that using `ContentUris`, and update the `is_ringtone` value alone using that `Uri` and `update()` with `ContentResolver`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thank you for your answer. I know you an expert, I read your blog about scoped storage yesterday. The "_data" is deprecated, but if I don't assign "_data", I'll get a crash java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Changing volume from /storage/13F8-0E1C/Music/test.mp3 to /storage/emulated/0/Music/test.mp3 not allowed. If I don't assign "_data" and "mime_type", I can change the type to ringtone without problem, but there are error log in logcat, Invalid image: ExifInterface got an unsupported image format file(ExifInterface supports JPEG and some RAW image formats only) ...

Comment: In my experiments, many columns in `MediaStore` appear to be non-updateable. It would be disappointing if `mime_type` were one, as you could easily change the MIME type of the content by writing to the `OutputStream`. In terms of the `ExifInterface` message, so long as that is not coming from your app and your ringtone state change is working, I would not worry about it.